# Why did the Red Queen try to exterminate humanity in Resident Evil: Retribution?

Tags: resident-evil

We may know in the next film. But for now: why did she try to do this?

The main rule for her is: Save humanity. So, in the first movie, it made a lot of sense when she killed everyone in the Hive. But she failed and now there are more zombies than humans.

So, to save humanity, does she need to completely destroy it and rebuild it again with clones?

Comment: I edited the question a little. I haven't seen the film yet, so I can't answer it. Feel free to roll it back if you disagree with the edit. :)

Comment: It's a good question. Personally, I think RE5 is when the series completely jumped the shark - even compared to the other four, this movie was a confusing, steaming mess.

Answer (score 2):

The Red Queen, as you said, was programmed to save humanity, also The Red Queen is a computer, and she calculates the maximum chances of survival of the human race using different scenarios based on the tests of the Russian facility. She must be seeing Alice as more of a threat to the tests than an aid she can use.

Your proposed explanation may be one possibility, the other being that she is in the process of finding the cure with the help of Alice's blood(was said in movie 3).

Comment: But Red queen doesn't tried to kill Alice but the whole humanity.

Comment: Like I said she might be needing Alice's blood for the cure

and anyways the sixth movie is the last installment so I guess the writers will answer this question.